# File and Insertion Sort. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, file, file-io, insertion-sort

This program **sorts the first n words from a file using insertion sort**.

**This is not made by me.** We were asked to use this program our teacher provided to implement other sorting techniques. I imported the source code and when I run it. It says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 
>       at SortingAnalysis.main(SortingAnalysis.java:26)

But when our teacher demonstrated it in our class, there is no error in it.

I'm also wondering **how it sorts the words from a file without even stating the file name** (e.g. tobesorted.txt). Maybe as long as it's within the JRE System Library, it will work, won't it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Compares the running times of sorting algorithms
 * @author bryann
 *
 */
public class SortingAnalysis {

    public static void insertionSort(String[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            String cur = a[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while((j >= 0) && (a[j].compareTo(cur) > 0)) {
                a[j + 1] = a[j--];
            } // end while
            a[j + 1] = cur;
        } // end for
    } // end insertionSort

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NO_OF_WORDS = 5000;
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            String[] words = new String[NO_OF_WORDS];

            int i = 0;
            while(file.hasNext() && i < NO_OF_WORDS) {
                words[i] = file.next();
                i++;
            } // end while
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            insertionSort(words);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Sorted Words: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(words[j]);
            } // end for        
            System.out.print("Running time of insertion sort: " + (end - start) + "ms");

        } // end try
        catch(SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("You do not have proper privilege to access the files.");
            System.exit(1);
        } // end catch
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error accessing file");
            System.exit(1);
        } // end catch
    } // end main
} // end class SortingAnalysis
```

**Is the error because of import?** Using Eclipse, I just clicked 
**File > Import > General > File System > From directory** (the whole folder he sent to us) **> Into folder** (I created a new project and there is where I "imported" the code) **> Finish**

Please help me. I can't start with the assignment (that is, trying other sorting techniques in the same source file) because I can't run it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Added the 'homework' tag... What have you tried, you could start with the eclipse debugger. In cases like this you should post the exception stack trace as well, it should show you where the exception occurs (line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function of a program takes arguments :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Those arguments are the ones passed to the program on the command line :

```
java SortingAnalysis /home/somebody/tobesorted.txt
```

In this case, `args[0]` would be `"/home/somebody/tobesorted.txt"`

This enables the program to know what file to open :

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

But when you launch your program without providing the path to a file, args is too short and you have this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 as args[0] doesn't exist` you got.

So give the path to the file to sort to remove this error. For example :

```
java SortingAnalysis C:\somepath\tobesorted.txt
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to hardcode the path, you may do this :

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\somepath\\tobesorted.txt"));
```

(note the double `\\`).

Comment: Thanks dystroy! Uhm, by path, you mean I should specify the directory?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to provide the whole path to the directory so you don't have to guess what is the *current* directory. I gave two examples, one with linux path and one with windows path.

Comment: Thanks again! In which part of the program should I write the path to the directory? (I'm sorry, dystroy, I'm new to the java language)

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you so much, dystroy! I didn't know \\ was possible. Now I can start with my assignment. Thank you!

Comment: "\\" escapes the "\" so that you can insert it in a string (that's the same in most languages).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

It's looking for the first argument passed in when you run it which is the words file. You need to run it as:

```
java SortingAnalysis wordsfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy Ray! I'm new in Java, I'm sorry but how can I run it as
java SortingAnalysis wordsfile.txt?